# Matplotlib arange categorical Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

i have categorical data on y axis and timestamps on x axis. [y axis order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6CBb.png)

The problem is i have different files, for each file i have to run the script. Sometimes there is no data for all 7 values on y axis. Sometimes its in another order (like "RUNNING", "UNUSED","PROBLEM").

The order is depending on the categorie in the excel file which is the first one.

Is there any way to arange these in a fixed way? Even if i dont have all categories in this sheet i would like to have them allways on y axis.

My idea was to put some dummydata bevore each dataframe, but i think thats an ugly solution.